Error in Return value must be of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
I am currently learning Laravel Filament, but suddenly there is an error like this. Previously, I fixed the error, but the result was not as expected.
This is a screenshot of the error result and its code.
Error Filament
 public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\Section::make('Relationships')
                    ->schema([
                        Forms\Components\Select::make('country_id')
                            ->relationship(name: 'country', titleAttribute: 'name')
                            ->searchable()
                            ->preload()
                            ->live()
                            ->required(),
                        Forms\Components\Select::make('state_id')
                            ->options(fn (Get $get): Collection => State::query()
                                ->where('country_id', $get('country_id'))
                                ->get()
                                ->pluck('name', 'id'))
                            ->searchable()
                            ->preload()
                            ->live()
                            ->required(),
                        Forms\Components\Select::make('city_id')
                            ->options(fn (Get $get): Collection => City::query()
                                ->where('state_id', $get('state_id'))
                                ->get()
                                ->pluck('name', 'id'))
                            ->searchable()
                            ->preload()
                            ->required(),

I want to know what the root cause of my code issue is.

The error is quite clear: the expected type is not being returned. For example from your codes, consider the following:
->options(fn (Get $get): Collection => State::query()
    ->where('country_id', $get('country_id'))
    ->get()
    ->pluck('name', 'id'))


Is Collection in this context referring to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection or Illuminate\Support\Collection?
Keep in mind that pluck() will transform your data into an Illuminate\Support\Collection.
You can adjust your return type accordingly.

The issue is the Collection return type declaration in the select options closure. Without knowing what the top of your php file looks like, I can assume that you may have this line at the top:
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
You are using pluck() after the get() statement in your Eloquent query, and the return type of that is Illuminate\Support\Collection, which causes the mismatch in the return type.
Try the following code instead, which uses the all() method to return an array from a collection, and sets array as the return type declaration for the closure:
public static function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        ->schema([
            Forms\Components\Section::make('Relationships')
                ->schema([
                    Forms\Components\Select::make('country_id')
                        ->relationship(name: 'country', titleAttribute: 'name')
                        ->searchable()
                        ->preload()
                        ->live()
                        ->required(),
                    Forms\Components\Select::make('state_id')
                        ->options(fn (Get $get): array => 
                            State::where('country_id', $get('country_id'))
                                ->pluck('name', 'id')
                                ->all())
                        ->searchable()
                        ->preload()
                        ->live()
                        ->required(),
                    Forms\Components\Select::make('city_id')
                        ->options(fn (Get $get): array => 
                            City::where('state_id', $get('state_id'))
                                ->pluck('name', 'id')
                                ->all())
                        ->searchable()
                        ->preload()
                        ->required(),

